# How to get a fast file Hashing algorithm for large files on a mobile device

Tags: android, java-native-interface, md5, hash, file-transfer

*prologue*
*However one important discovery i make during testing the md5, adler32 and crc32 on a 100Mb file, is that strangely it take the same time. This can only mean one of two thing i guess, that on The Android device, the filesystem is the bottleneck and it cannot feed the algorithm fast enough, or i made a fundamental error implementing JNI, the later one i could live with.*

Hashing small files like images, mp3 and files under 10Mb take seconds using the MD5 
algorithm.

My problem is i have files with sizes over 100-700MB.

My requirement is that downloaded files need to match the original source file.

I did some tests for making MD5 hashes for a file with the size of 100Mb.

On the device HTC Desire Android v2.2 i run both a jni native test and
the java `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");` test.

Both tests calculated the MD5 of the same file and both test run approximation for the same length of time 1-2min. I had debugging turned of.

It was my understanding that the Native test would be faster.

How can i get the hashing time down to let say 10-15sec for 100MB on the above device.
The cost for this is of course collision accuracy but i can live with that the hash is not same in one in a million.

*UPDATE*
Im no c guru but here is my test c-code for MD5. The speed on this one was not not much faster then the Java `MessageDigest` . Felt like i was running on the Android main UI thread.

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* typedef a 32 bit type */
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;

/* Data structure for MD5 (Message Digest) computation */
typedef struct {
  UINT4 i[2];                   /* number of _bits_ handled mod 2^64 */
  UINT4 buf[4];                                    /* scratch buffer */
  unsigned char in[64];                              /* input buffer */
  unsigned char digest[16];     /* actual digest after MD5Final call */
} MD5_CTX;

void MD5Init ();
void MD5Update ();
void MD5Final ();



/* forward declaration */
static void Transform ();

static unsigned char PADDING[64] = {
  0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

/* F, G and H are basic MD5 functions: selection, majority, parity */
#define F(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) | ((~x) & (z)))
#define G(x, y, z) (((x) & (z)) | ((y) & (~z)))
#define H(x, y, z) ((x) ^ (y) ^ (z))
#define I(x, y, z) ((y) ^ ((x) | (~z)))

/* ROTATE_LEFT rotates x left n bits */
#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))

/* FF, GG, HH, and II transformations for rounds 1, 2, 3, and 4 */
/* Rotation is separate from addition to prevent recomputation */
#define FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += F ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += G ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += H ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }
#define II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) \
  {(a) += I ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
   (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
   (a) += (b); \
  }

void MD5Init (mdContext)
MD5_CTX *mdContext;
{
  mdContext->i[0] = mdContext->i[1] = (UINT4)0;

  /* Load magic initialization constants.
   */
  mdContext->buf[0] = (UINT4)0x67452301;
  mdContext->buf[1] = (UINT4)0xefcdab89;
  mdContext->buf[2] = (UINT4)0x98badcfe;
  mdContext->buf[3] = (UINT4)0x10325476;
}

void MD5Update (mdContext, inBuf, inLen)
MD5_CTX *mdContext;
unsigned char *inBuf;
unsigned int inLen;
{
  UINT4 in[16];
  int mdi;
  unsigned int i, ii;

  /* compute number of bytes mod 64 */
  mdi = (int)((mdContext->i[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

  /* update number of bits */
  if ((mdContext->i[0] + ((UINT4)inLen << 3)) < mdContext->i[0])
    mdContext->i[1]++;
  mdContext->i[0] += ((UINT4)inLen << 3);
  mdContext->i[1] += ((UINT4)inLen >> 29);

  while (inLen--) {
    /* add new character to buffer, increment mdi */
    mdContext->in[mdi++] = *inBuf++;

    /* transform if necessary */
    if (mdi == 0x40) {
      for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 16; i++, ii += 4)
        in[i] = (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+3]) << 24) |
                (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+2]) << 16) |
                (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+1]) << 8) |
                ((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii]);
      Transform (mdContext->buf, in);
      mdi = 0;
    }
  }
}

void MD5Final (mdContext)
MD5_CTX *mdContext;
{
  UINT4 in[16];
  int mdi;
  unsigned int i, ii;
  unsigned int padLen;

  /* save number of bits */
  in[14] = mdContext->i[0];
  in[15] = mdContext->i[1];

  /* compute number of bytes mod 64 */
  mdi = (int)((mdContext->i[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

  /* pad out to 56 mod 64 */
  padLen = (mdi < 56) ? (56 - mdi) : (120 - mdi);
  MD5Update (mdContext, PADDING, padLen);

  /* append length in bits and transform */
  for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 14; i++, ii += 4)
    in[i] = (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+3]) << 24) |
            (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+2]) << 16) |
            (((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii+1]) << 8) |
            ((UINT4)mdContext->in[ii]);
  Transform (mdContext->buf, in);

  /* store buffer in digest */
  for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 4; i++, ii += 4) {
    mdContext->digest[ii] = (unsigned char)(mdContext->buf[i] & 0xFF);
    mdContext->digest[ii+1] =
      (unsigned char)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
    mdContext->digest[ii+2] =
      (unsigned char)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
    mdContext->digest[ii+3] =
      (unsigned char)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 24) & 0xFF);
  }
}

/* Basic MD5 step. Transform buf based on in.
 */
static void Transform (buf, in)
UINT4 *buf;
UINT4 *in;
{
  UINT4 a = buf[0], b = buf[1], c = buf[2], d = buf[3];

  /* Round 1 */
#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 0], S11, 3614090360u); /* 1 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 1], S12, 3905402710u); /* 2 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[ 2], S13,  606105819u); /* 3 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[ 3], S14, 3250441966u); /* 4 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 4], S11, 4118548399u); /* 5 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 5], S12, 1200080426u); /* 6 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[ 6], S13, 2821735955u); /* 7 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[ 7], S14, 4249261313u); /* 8 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 8], S11, 1770035416u); /* 9 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 9], S12, 2336552879u); /* 10 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[10], S13, 4294925233u); /* 11 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[11], S14, 2304563134u); /* 12 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[12], S11, 1804603682u); /* 13 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[13], S12, 4254626195u); /* 14 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[14], S13, 2792965006u); /* 15 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[15], S14, 1236535329u); /* 16 */

  /* Round 2 */
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 1], S21, 4129170786u); /* 17 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[ 6], S22, 3225465664u); /* 18 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[11], S23,  643717713u); /* 19 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 0], S24, 3921069994u); /* 20 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 5], S21, 3593408605u); /* 21 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[10], S22,   38016083u); /* 22 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[15], S23, 3634488961u); /* 23 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 4], S24, 3889429448u); /* 24 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 9], S21,  568446438u); /* 25 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[14], S22, 3275163606u); /* 26 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[ 3], S23, 4107603335u); /* 27 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 8], S24, 1163531501u); /* 28 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[13], S21, 2850285829u); /* 29 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[ 2], S22, 4243563512u); /* 30 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[ 7], S23, 1735328473u); /* 31 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[12], S24, 2368359562u); /* 32 */

  /* Round 3 */
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 5], S31, 4294588738u); /* 33 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 8], S32, 2272392833u); /* 34 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[11], S33, 1839030562u); /* 35 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[14], S34, 4259657740u); /* 36 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 1], S31, 2763975236u); /* 37 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 4], S32, 1272893353u); /* 38 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[ 7], S33, 4139469664u); /* 39 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[10], S34, 3200236656u); /* 40 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[13], S31,  681279174u); /* 41 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 0], S32, 3936430074u); /* 42 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[ 3], S33, 3572445317u); /* 43 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[ 6], S34,   76029189u); /* 44 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 9], S31, 3654602809u); /* 45 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[12], S32, 3873151461u); /* 46 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[15], S33,  530742520u); /* 47 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[ 2], S34, 3299628645u); /* 48 */

  /* Round 4 */
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 0], S41, 4096336452u); /* 49 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[ 7], S42, 1126891415u); /* 50 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[14], S43, 2878612391u); /* 51 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 5], S44, 4237533241u); /* 52 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[12], S41, 1700485571u); /* 53 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[ 3], S42, 2399980690u); /* 54 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[10], S43, 4293915773u); /* 55 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 1], S44, 2240044497u); /* 56 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 8], S41, 1873313359u); /* 57 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[15], S42, 4264355552u); /* 58 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[ 6], S43, 2734768916u); /* 59 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[13], S44, 1309151649u); /* 60 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 4], S41, 4149444226u); /* 61 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[11], S42, 3174756917u); /* 62 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[ 2], S43,  718787259u); /* 63 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 9], S44, 3951481745u); /* 64 */

  buf[0] += a;
  buf[1] += b;
  buf[2] += c;
  buf[3] += d;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring
    Java_com_carlsberg_IntentServiceSendFiles_gethash( JNIEnv* env,  jobject thiz ,
 jstring filename)
{

    const char *fi = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,filename, 0);

      FILE *inFile = fopen (fi, "rb");
      MD5_CTX mdContext;
      int bytes;
      unsigned char data[1024];

      if (inFile == NULL) {
        printf ("%s can't be opened.\n",fi);
        return;
      }

      MD5Init (&mdContext);
      while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, inFile)) != 0)
      MD5Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
      MD5Final (&mdContext);
      fclose (inFile);

      char tempValue[33]; // 32 hex digits + 0-terminator
      int i;
      // convert to hex
      for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
          sprintf(tempValue + 2*i, "%02x", (unsigned char)mdContext.digest[i]);

      return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,tempValue );

}
```

Comment: What amount of certainty do you need that the files match? You could md5 just the first 1000 bytes or the first meg. Unfortunately, beyond that, reading the file off the storage medium and running the md5 requires reading the entire file from, since its large, sdcard. Its going to be slow. Maybe use a CRC instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099349/difference-between-crc-and-hash-method-md5-sha1

Comment: @Nick Campion The file has to match. Unfortunate i cannot only read the first 1000 only. will look into CRC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android uses [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) for the crytpoapi which implements all its digest algorithms in java. So you are right, it should be faster when it's done entirely native. When you have the knowledge and time (and the need to) use them in native code, it will be (according to your measurements) a little bit faster.

You sould also use TCP or another protocol which ensures that data arrives correctly (I guess you already use TCP and not UDP as you use FTP)

What I would do is the following in this case:

I would create 2 new threads (besides the UI thread which does some fancy progressbar printing) where the first is responsible for the download and the second is responsible for the hashing.

The download thread would now notify the hashing thread about newly arrived chunks. The chunks could be 10MB or so. So the hashing thread processes only 10MB chunks which should be reasonable fast and should also preserve the ability to notice file breaks early. With this approach you could also detect when the download broke and could redownload the file with the first broken chunk. Of course you would have to create and transfer a chunklist to the client before this can work.

You can also use a very fast hashing algo here which is suitable to detect transfer breaks (which shouldn't come up as you use TCP which guarantees that the data arrives correctly if send so).

After reading my text again this feels somewhat like a torrent (chunkbased, hashed to see if everything is correct, able to retransmit...).

Bonus points: do it in native code so it's a little bit faster.

Comment: looks like your answer is the best.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the rsync approach i.e. initially use a fast hash such as Adler32 or CRC-32 and only use the slower MD5 when you get a collision on the fast hash.

Comment: After reading about the rsync and Adler32 and crc i think i go with the later faster once. will run som tests on crc and adler. I have no choose since speed is critical. Updated my question with the c-code MD5

Comment: Make sure you're using a table driven implementation if it's speed that is critical. I generally use Mark Nelson's implementations (e.g. http://marknelson.us/1992/05/01/file-verification-using-crc-2) but there are lots of others around. CRC-16 is faster than CRC-32 but obviously with more chance of collisions (roughly 1 in 65536 on the size of files  that you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks, wanted to right away to test the CRC-16 and some snipes from the Nelson's implementations. However one important discovery i make during testing the md5, adler32 and crc32 on a 100Mb file, is that strangely it take the same time. This can only mean one of two thing i guess, that on The Android device, the filesystem is the bottleneck and it cannot feed the algorithm fast enough, or i made a fundamental error implementing JNI.

Comment: Figures ... SDCARDS aren't known for being blazingly fast :-(. Might be worth seeing if calculating the hash values while downloading the file works better.

Comment: that was a good ide. One could feed the algorithm at the same time whens uploading still what about when transfer crash and resume. take some really fancy coding to make that robust.

Comment: Not really - just bookmark where you had hashed up to and when the resume gets past that point continue with the hash from where you left off.

Comment: sound good would love to see some pseudo code on that. and what algorithm is suitable crc32 maybe. The `java.util.zip.CRC32.CRC32()` class has to (in my case) be recreated on resume. or else the `CRC32.update(int val)` will start from beginning again.